# I cannot change the link color of the text in my footer, using wordpress for the first time

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have never used wordpress before, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the link color in the footer text. I have legitimately been trying for hours.

http://4f3.b63.myftpupload.com/

style.css 
and bootstrap.min.css

I'm about to give up.

Comment: Just some advice: You might want to edit out "...and with good reason..."  Others may think that you're taking a jab at Wordpress, which could start a flame war.  Charged language of that nature is generally discouraged on SO.  I think this is a good question, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the link you are referring to but try .textwidget h6 { color: (yourcolor); }

Comment: Can you please make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or add a minimum amount of code to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to edit your stylesheets in Wordpress, all you need is a new CSS declaration:

```
footer#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Using the combined element and id selector will ensure that your rule is specific enough to override the current color.